# How to change python3 version on mac to 3.10.10

Tags: python, installation, pip, version, upgrade

I am currently running python 3.9.13 on my mac. I wanted to update my version to 3.10.10

I tried running

```
brew install python
```

However it says that "python 3.10.10 is already installed"!

When i run

```
python3 --version
```

in the terminal it says that i am still on "python 3.9.13"

So my question is, how do i change the python version from 3.9.13 to 3.10.10? I already deleted python 3.9 from my applications and python 3.10 is the only one that is still there.

I also tried to install python 3.10.10 from the website and installing it. However it does not work. Python 3.10.10 is being installed successfully but the version is still the same when i check it.

Answer (score 17):

you can use `pyenv` to work with multiple python environments

things to do:

1. install pyenv : `brew install pyenv`[official installation guide](https://github.com/pyenv/pyenv#installation)
2. install particular python: `pyenv install 3.10.10`
3. set python3.10.10 to gloabal python env: `pyenv global 3.10.10`

and can start using `python 3.10.10` version

in my opinion, if you are not good with the terminal or how python is configured in mac system, it is better to leave the original system Python as it is. and use a separate Python manager to help you manage the different Python version independently if something wrong goes then it only affect the environment not the system

Answer (score 3):

I had the same problem upgrading from 3.8 to 3.11 on macOS until I realized I needed to end my terminal session and start a new one.  Then the *python3 --version* command reported the new version.

Answer (score 1):

Python `3.10.10` is already installed along with Python `3.9.13`. Your path is probably pointing to `3.9.13` and that's why you're getting that Python version.

Try modifying your path variable to point to brew's Python installation, or (better yet) make use of a virtual environment.

a) Telling what Python version your `PATH` variable is pointing to:

```
$ which python
```

Will tell you what's the actual executable's path. That way, you are going to see exactly where you main python resides.

b) If you want to create a virtual environment with brew's python try something like:

```
$ /usr/local/Cellar/python@3.10/3.10.1/bin/python3 -m venv py310
$ source venv/bin/activate
$ python
> # you should be inside a 3.10.1 envornamente
> CTRL+D
$ pip install requests
```

Comment: What command do i need to run to change the path variable to point to brew's python installation? When i run "which python" it says "user/miniforge3/bin/python"

Comment: It depends on what's the shell you're using. Is it bash? Is it zsh? What does the command `$ echo $SHELL` tells you?

Comment: Iam using the zsh shell :)

Comment: Then  you can edit the `~/.zshrc` file to set your PATH variable accordingly.

Answer (score 1):

When you download latest version, it comes with a file named `Update Shell Profile.command`.

In mac, you can find it at `/Applications/Python 3.11/Update Shell Profile.command`.

Run it and it should upgrade to latest version.

Answer (score 0):

Just delete the current python installation on your device and download the version you want from the offical website. That is the easiest way and the most suitable one for a beginner.

Comment: I did that however when i run the command "python3 --version" it still shows my old version

Comment: I believe you weren't able to delete python in a proper way. Try using this command **sudo pkgutil --forget python3**. If that doesn't work you can also try **[user name] sudo rm -rf /Applications/Python\ [your_python_version]/**.